# Codeigniter: Change languages on the fly (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to work out how to change the languages on the fly using the Codeigniter Language System. So I made this ajax call which works but obviosly the values won't change until I reload the page unlease I somehow print out the values or set the variables in the function which is being called by AJAX ? What is the best way of doing this.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.lang-choices a').on('click' , function() {
      var language = $(this).attr("data-lang");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: js_site_url('langswitch/switchLanguage'),
        data: "requestedLanguage=" + language,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        },
        error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
      }); 
    return false;  
    }); 
});
</script>
```

switchLanguage Function

```
  public function switchLanguage() 
  {
    $language = $this->input->post('requestedLanguage');
    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
  }
```

Comment: A simple ajax call isn't going to rerender the page. If you want to change the language of a rendered page you need to search and replace all items with the new language strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit unclear so the assumption I'm making is that you're flipping a backend flag that changes the output from the server. Using that assumption, here's what I'd recommend in order of magnitude:

- In your `success` handler, reload the page using `window.location.reload(true)`. The true argument is essential since it makes a trip to the server to get new data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload
- Your success handler seems to take html as an arg. I'm not sure if you're actually sending that based on your `switchLanguage` function or if that's leftover from copy+paste somewhere. If you are indeed getting HTML data and it's page data, I'd use the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to filter down to the content of the document you're receiving then replace my page's content with this data

Here's an example of the latter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: js_site_url( 'langswitch/switchLanguage' ),
    data: 'requestedLanguage=' + language,
    cache: false,
    context: document.body,
    success: function( html ){
        // or similar
        $( 'body' ).replaceWith( html );
    },
    error: function( exception ) {
        alert( 'Exeption:' + exception );
    } 
});
```